# Make in order mysql column by the most repeated value and show in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want put in order some column in order by the most repeated value 
 
like this :
ID  Name              Link 
1    Màh Di            www.website1.com
2    Fallaga Team    www.website2.com
3    PRG                         www.website3.com
4    Fallaga Team    www.website4.com
5    Fallaga Team    www.website5.com
6    Màh Di            www.website6.com
7    Màh Di            www.website7.com
8    PRG                www.website8.com
9    Fallaga Team   www.website9.com
10   Fallaga Team   www.website10.com

I want show them in php like this :

1 Fallaga Team 5 times
2  Màh Di          3 times

 3 PRG             2 times

I tried this:

```
$qer = "SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS popularity
FROM fallaga_tbl
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY popularity DESC limit 2;";
$resu = mysql_query($qer, $conn );
$ro = mysql_fetch_row($resu) ;
```

In the body i put this :

```
while($ro = mysql_fetch_array($resu, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    echo "<tr> ".
         "<td class=\"tg-032e\"><a href=\"Names/{$ro['Name']}\">{$ro['Name']}</a></td></tr>";
        } 
mysql_close($conn);
```

But it's not working fine also it shows just the name and i want to show also how much it repeats and in order
Can someone help me ?
And thank you

Comment: change `GROUP BY id` to `GROUP BY Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you have to do 
1) Make query

```
$qer = "SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS popularity FROM fallaga_tbl GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY popularity DESC limit 2";
```

2) In your while loop to get name and count

```
while($ro = mysql_fetch_array($resu, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<p>".$ro['Name'].":".$ro['popularity']."</p>";

} 
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: Now it just show the second one like this  `Màh Di  3 times` but the first one which is `Fallaga Team 5 times` is not showing (i don't need the third )

Comment: do you have any solution

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your `Group By` clause, What you need is count popularity based on repetation  of `Name` field, then you should group by `Name` instead `id` of row.

Try this query:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS popularity
FROM fallaga_tbl
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY popularity DESC limit 2;
```

Comment: Now it just show the second one like this 
`Màh Di  3 times` but the first one which is `Fallaga Team 5 times` is not showing (i don't need the third )